# Film Trailer or Film's Trailer?

Tags: grammar

What's the correct way to say a movie trailer? for example: "Inside out's trailer" or "Inside out Trailer"?

Comment: What makes you think one of them is wrong?

Comment: Because in you would assume that film would have something to do with trailer, as in film teaolrt could be a trailer made out of film, inside out trailer could be a trailer turned inside out

Comment: Correct punctuation and formatting would prevent any misunderstanding of that sort. Film titles should be in italics or quotes. Whether you add an apostrophe is irrelevant. _Inside Out_'s trailer.  "Inside Out" Trailer. Also, if 'inside out' is an adjective before a noun it is hyphenated to avoid such confusion - "This coat is inside out" OR "The inside-out coat was left on the hook". Punctuation is there for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most "proper" way would be:

> We saw the trailer for *Inside Out*.

However, neither of your variations are strictly incorrect.  The trailer is tied to the movie, so using the possessive makes sense.  It also makes sense to qualify the word "trailer" by using the movie title as an adjective phrase.

Regarding your comment:

> If I were to say "Have you seen the *Broken* trailer?" it could mean a trailer that is broken; if you have no context you can't know.

Ambiguity doesn't make a construction incorrect, *especially* when it depends on the context and the specific words used rather than the function of those words and the form of the sentence.  "Have you seen the *Finding Nemo* trailer?" wouldn't become incorrect just because a different movie title could confuse the listener.

Comment: +1 Ambiguity quite often happens in everyday speech, you can't prevent every eventuality, and it's often the basis for humour.

Answer (score 1):

Usually people say "the Inside Out trailer."

Comment: That would still be ambiguous though, if I were to say: "have you seen the broken trailer?" it could mean a trailer that is broken, if you have no cobtext you can't know

Comment: True. In cases like that, people sometimes will say something like "the trailer for Broken, the movie." You can always add more words for clarity.

Comment: Putting the name of the film in Italics would help. 'Have you seen the *Inside Out* trailer?'